# Texture Painting Help

Tags: node-editor, texture-painting

[image]I do have a basic scene (demonstration)

Texture painted sphere (red color based and white plus (+) on it.
The thing i want to achieve is keep that white part (kinda lock it) and change that red part with nodes whenever i need it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I would convert the texture to its green channel as a file, but if you need to keep it red, you can do it nodewise with the Separate RGB node, then use the green output. In either case, use the result as the factor of a Mix RGB node to mix between whatever color you want (color 1) for the rest of the ball, and white (color 2) for the plus sign.